# PHP Session (Login page and userpage)

Tags: php

I need to create a session on index page
if user already login in, it will header to member page.
if user destroy session, it will stay at index(login page)

what i did is

```
if(session_start){
    header("location:member.php") or die();
}

if(isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['password'])){



$email=strtolower($_POST['email']);
    $password=md5($_POST['password']);



if($email && $password){
        $connect=mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
        $database=mysql_select_db("phplogin", $connect);



$SQL=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email'");
        $numrows=mysql_num_rows($SQL);



if($numrows!=0){
            while($result=mysql_fetch_assoc($SQL)){
                $db_email=$result['email'];
                $db_password=$result['password'];
                $db_firstname=$result['firstname'];
                $db_lastname=$result['lastname'];
                }
            }
        else{
            die("Can't find the user");
            }



if($email==$db_email && $password==$db_password){
            session_start();
            $_SESSION['firstname']=$db_firstname;
            $_SESSION['lastname']=$db_lastname;
            header("location:member.php");
            }   
        else{   
            die("wrong username or password");
            }
        }
    else{die("Please enter email or password");}
    }
```

This works when user haven't destroy session, but when user destroy session
it didn't stay at index page

I need something like facebook, yet I don't know how facebook can share same the domain name on login page and user page.

so everytime i type facebook.com i will go to my user page, if i logout, it will become login page

Comment: To do something like facebook, you need to configure your webserver, most likely apache. There you can route incoming requests. By the way, using mysql_query is unsafe, you should use PDO or mysqli library. And also, session_start is a function and you should have cookies enabled. Are those correct?

Comment: you are using `session_start()` when you are checking the input values with db values. remove that from where you have written and add `session_start()` at the top of the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have used `if(session_start)`. `session_start()` is a function. And it is used on each and every page. So it will redirect you everytime.

Another thing, you need to `session_start()` on the page you are storing the session and the page you are getting session values.

Instead of:

```
if(session_start){
    header("location:member.php") or die();
}
```

Use:

```
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['firstname']) && isset($_SESSION['lastname'])){
    header('location:member.php');
}
//and REMOVE session_start(); from where you have written.
```

Answer (score 0):

How about on top of your page

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['firstname']) || !isset($_SESSION['lastname'])){
    header("location:index.php") or die();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all; only checking if a session exists isn't enough if you want to check if your user is logged in (the session could exist all the same, even if the user isn't logged in). So you should write a `is_logged_in()` function (or something like that) first to properly check the logged in status.

The reason why your user is always redirected is because the function `session_start()` returns `true` if a session is started succesfully; if the session is destroyed, it just starts a new one. So basically it will return `true` pretty much always, if everything works correctly (like user has not turned cookies off etc.).

If you have written that function it's actually quite simple. Let's pretend you have two files: `home.php` and `member.php`. The first one is your homepage (with a "Hello visitor!" message and the login form), the second is the member page. If both files are 'standalone' scripts you can indeed header the user to the specific page (`header('Location: home.php');` if user should login first, `header('Location: member.php');` if user is already logged in).

But! If you want to 'cloak' the pages (pretty much like facebook does it), you can just include the files in your index.php. Do something like this:

```
if(is_logged_in()) {
    require_once('member.php'); // present member profile page
} else {
    require_once('home.php'); // present login page
}
```

In your index.php you can set a constant (see also [the php manual about constants](https://www.php.net/constants)) to be sure the files can only be included from within index.php:

--- index.php:

```
define('VALID_INCLUDE', true);
// the rest of your code
```

--- home.php & member.php:

```
if(!defined('VALID_INCLUDE')) die('You should not request this page directly');
```

But please note that if you want to write applications like this, a framework could help you a lot; it covers a lot if this kind of problems and makes coding a lot faster (most frameworks come with a authentication modules of some sort, and allow you to use 'views' to present your user with the proper pages, like I have done above with the `require_once` solution).